# Does the 'cp' command continue to copy all files if it has a permissions problem with one file or folder?

Tags: bash, cp, posix, macos, bsd

In OS X Mojave / bash, I am in my home directory copying all files using the `cp` command from the directory `~/Pictures/` to `~/Dropbox/Pictures/` and as often happens when copying without `sudo` on *nix, I run into permissions errors:

```bsh
# Apple won't let you put this folder in iCloud Drive, hello Dropbox!
$ cp -rp Pictures/* ~/Dropbox/Pictures/

cp: Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary: unable to copy extended attributes to
/Users/rjurney/Dropbox/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary: Operation not permitted

cp: Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary: Operation not permitted
```

In the presence of permissions errors like this one, can I count on the rest of the `cp` operation succeeding? I *think* the behavior is the same across *nix/bash environments so I'm asking here rather than in a Mac forum.

Note: the `cp` command in question is described via `info cp` as:

```bsh
CP(1)                     BSD General Commands Manual                    CP(1)
...
STANDARDS
     The cp command is expected to be IEEE Std 1003.2 (``POSIX.2'') compatible.

HISTORY
     A cp command appeared in Version 1 AT&T UNIX.

BSD                            February 23, 2005                           BSD
```

*The reason for the copy is [iCloud can't backup `~/Pictures/`](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8037059?login=true)*

Answer (score 1):

While using `cp` if you own some files you are trying to move then (are the owner or in the group owner) **yes** they will be copied otherwise the rest of the files which you dont have permissions for will throw an error once the files you DO have permissions on have been copied.

Comment: Actually this isn't a Mac thing at all, note that this is BSD `cp` and it is POSIX compliant. I just happened to explain my use case. The same thing happens to every *nix user. I just wanted to know how BSD and other POSIX `cp`s fail when they hit permissions problems. You can pretend I never mentioned a Mac and this is a perfect question for this forum. I'm not sure an explanation of sudo is relevant, I mention it only because copying system directories in *nix without `sudo` often runs into such permissions errors, especially on OS X. I checked BSD and Linux and they behave the same way.

Comment: @rjurney okay I edited the reply is that better for you